# Creating own API gateway for microservices written nodejs/nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nginx, microservices, nestjs, api-gateway

I recently got into microservices, and I discovered API Gateway pattern that seems to be suitable for pretty much all kinds of situation.

As a way to learn this pattern, I created a nodejs project using nestjs framework.

What I am trying to implement is simple.

Simple blog platform website where user can view blog posts and create a blog post when signed in.

Below is step-by-step procedures:

1. Build API Gateway as single access point for client.
2. When client makes request to service that requires authentication, API gateway, instead of sending user to the service, will redirect user to first authenticate through my authentication service.
3. Once authentication service verifies the user, it will send 200 response to the API-Gateway with jwt attached to the user cookie.
4. Gateway will see the user is authenticated and directs the client to the Post service.

---

So far so good.

What I am wondering, though, is how to build this API gateway in the first place.

1. Should I build API Gateway in nestjs? express? or nginx? What would be suitable choice in general?
2. In case I am building a gateway other than nestjs, how would I be able to make them work together?

I can see my questions being too generic, but I'm basically looking for guideline in building such service.

Comment: I have worked on NGINX as well as express option of Gateway, both worked well. Even you can use some enterprise level API Gateways like Apigee etc. Also there should not be any issue in communication between Gateway and Microservices if Microservices provide standard protocols.

Comment: @xs2tarunkukreja Thanks for the response. Any suggestion on learning resource for building API gateway?